# Kivy FileChooserListView - Modifying the display of the file list?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I was wondering if anyone knew how to add numbers (purely for reference) to Kivy's FileChooserListView such that the file list is displayed like:

```
#  Name       Size
1. File 1       2k
2. File 2       2k
3. File 3       2k
...
```

Comment: There seems to be an `index` property that's floating around in the source. However, I'm not familiar with the code enough to know if this is available to users. I can try to take a look tonight.

Comment: Mixed success on this. I got an index to display but both directories and files were included. However, the script crashed when I tried to change to a subfolder. Unfortunately I just don't understand enough about how the ListViews work to be able solve this for you.

Comment: well, that sounds promising at least. I won't be needing to traverse directories in my app, so it may still work for my purposes. Did you somehow modify the built in class FileChooserListView or roll your own? would you mind posting your code? Even if it's not entirely functional, it may give me somewhere to start. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

OK, it's not a perfect answer but here's what I tried to do:

First thing was to edit kivy's default `filechooser.py` file. Find this section:

```
    ctx = {'name': basename(fn),
           'get_nice_size': get_nice_size,
           'path': fn,
           'controller': wself,
           'isdir': self.file_system.is_dir(fn),
           'parent': parent,
           'sep': sep}
```

and change it to:

```
    ctx = {'name': basename(fn),
           'get_nice_size': get_nice_size,
           'path': fn,
           'controller': wself,
           'isdir': self.file_system.is_dir(fn),
           'parent': parent,
           'sep': sep,
           'index': index}
```

Next up, find kivy's `style.kv` file (you could probably create a custom class to do this but I was being lazy!). Look for this section `[FileListEntry@FloatLayout+TreeViewNode]:`

I then took this part:

```
Label:
    id: filename
    text_size: self.width, None
    halign: 'left'
    shorten: True
    text: ctx.name
```

and changed it to:

```
Label:
    id: filename
    text_size: self.width, None
    halign: 'left'
    shorten: True
    text: "{}. {}".format(ctx.index, ctx.name)
```

As per my comment above, it seems to throw an error if you try to navigate folders.

It may be the case that one of the kivy experts knows a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite late but to complete the answer of elParaguayo, you also have to replace the lines

```
pardir = self._create_entry_widget(dict(
            name=back, size='', path=new_path, controller=ref(self),
            isdir=True, parent=None, sep=sep,
            get_nice_size=lambda: ''))
```

with

```
       pardir = self._create_entry_widget(dict(
            name=back, size='', path=new_path, controller=ref(self),
            isdir=True, parent=None, sep=sep,
            get_nice_size=lambda: '', index= 0))
```

(be careful there are 2 occurences of these lines). This is what throws the exception when you navigate: the parent directory `../` is not created with the same lines as the other files.

Also, I would advise to create a local copy of `filechooser.py` and `style.kv` and load them into your app instead of modifying the source code of the kivy modules.